# Scala - fold - List of tuples (Long, String) to List of Strings to single String

Tags: scala, fold

Basically want to do what the title states.

I have a `List[(Long, String)]` where `Long` is a row number and `String` is a column name. I want to output the list of tuples as a list of Strings, with each string being in the following format:

`index : row, column`

E.g.

`1: 3, column1`

`2: 7, column3` ...

I then want to flatten that

I want to create the index while doing this. So to do so I thought I would use `zipWithIndex` on the list and then fold that. I'm still unsure about folding. I understand that you give it an initial value and then it recursively returns the product of that initial value and an operation (am I correct?). However, I do struggle to understand how I would do what I've explained. Any suggestions/ help/ explanations would be very helpful.

```
recordList.zipWithIndex.fold(List.empty[(Int, String)]) {
    case (... that record in recordList exists?...) =>
        s"${index.toString} : $row , $column \n" // to be single record in final list
}.mkString(" \n")
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work. It's just an example of what I think I would want to try and do.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
recordList
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { case (v, index) => s"$index: ${v._1}, ${v._2}" }
  .mkString("\n")
```

which outputs

```
0: 3, column1
1: 2, column2
2: 7, column3
```

given

```
val recordList: List[(Long, String)] = List((3, "column1"), (2, "column2"), (7, "column3"))
```

Using foldLeft try

```
recordList.foldLeft[(String, Iterator[Int])](("", LazyList.iterate(0)(_ + 1).iterator)) {
  case ((acc, index), v) => s"$acc \n ${index.next}: ${v._1}, ${v._2}" -> index
}._1
```

Comment: Will that include the index in the string?

Comment: (row, column) is a location in this case.  I want an index as well as the row and column so that a user knows which location they are looking up.

Comment: May I suggest 'zipWithIndex' ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `foldLeft` a simple `map` is enough :

```
val l: List[(Long, String)] = List((3L, "col1"), (7L, "col2"))

l.zip(Stream from 1).map{ case (value, index) => s"$index: ${value._1}, ${value._2}" }.mkString("\n")
```

Note, I usually prefer `zip(Stream from 1)` instead of `zipWithIndex` and add `1` manually later. Find it clearer !